# Why is my "Set Next Statement" disabled?

Tags: windows, eclipse, python-2.7, 64-bit, pydev

I use the `Eclipse/Run/Set Next Statement` quite often when debugging, but recently it seems to be disabled all the time:

[image]

I am in the *debug* perspective when trying to use it and I can use the other methods `Step over`, `Step into`, etc.

Is it something I need to configure, is it an incompatibility issue or am I facing a bug somewhere?

I am using Eclipse 4.7.1a, PyDev 6.2.0 and Python 2.7.x (x64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the `Set next statement` again I changed to `Debug perspective` and went into `Window/Perspective/Customize Perspective` and I could enable it again:

[image: How to enable "set next statement"]

Under the third tab `Action Set Availability` enable `PyDev Set Next Statement` like in the image above.

I suspect it became disabled due to a [bug](https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/859) fixed in Pydev 6.1.0.